# How to remove 'SCHEDULED' timestamp when changing TODO state to WAITING

Tags: org-mode

I have some item in an org buffer marked as TODO and having a scheduled timestamp:

```
* TODO do something
  SCHEDULED: <2014-11-02 Sun>
```

How do I cause the SCHEDULED timestamp to be removed when I move this item to the 'waiting' state?

Comment: Why do you want it to be removed? Is it for the purpose of not showing up on the agenda?

Comment: I'd like it removed because by default I don't schedule WAITING items. But I'd like it to still show up on the Agenda if SCHEDULED because sometimes I do schedule them (e.g. to check in after X days of WAITING).

Comment: Yes, it's for the purpose of not showing up on the agenda - Generally it's some task I did work on, and now am waiting for a response to an email.  So transitioning it to 'WAITING' indicates that I *can't* work on it now, and want the scheduled timestamp to leave (Of course, if I later add a scheduled timestamp to it, I want it to show up again).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe something like this (tested briefly from buffer and agenda)

```
(defun rasmus/remove-schedule ()
  "Remove SCHEDULED-cookie is switching state to WAITING."
  (save-excursion
(and (equal (org-get-todo-state) "WAITING")
     (org-get-scheduled-time (point))
     (when (search-forward-regexp org-scheduled-time-regexp nil t)
       (or (delete-region (match-beginning 0) (match-end 0)) t))
     (get-buffer "*Org Agenda*")
     (with-current-buffer "*Org Agenda*"
       (org-agenda-redo)))))

(add-hook 'org-after-todo-state-change-hook
     'rasmus/remove-schedule)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're doing this so that `WAITING` items don't show up in the
agenda buffer, I'd like to suggest an alternative.

You can define `WAITING` to be a `DONE`-type keyword. These can easily
be configured to not display in the agenda, even when they have a
schedule. You can do that globally with this:

```
(setq org-todo-keywords '((sequence "TODO" "|" "WAITING" "DONE")))
```

Or on a per-file basis with this header:

```
#+SEQ_TODO: TODO | WAITING DONE
```

Then, to have these items not display in the agenda, just make sure you set:

```
(setq org-agenda-skip-scheduled-if-done t)
```

---

Finally, if you occasionally need a `WAITING` item to be displayed in
the agenda, set a `DEADLINE` on it instead of a `SCHEDULE`. The
display of deadlines is controlled by a different variable
(`org-agenda-skip-deadline-if-done` ), so they will still display in the agenda.

Comment: If you use done logging this will create a done log for waiting, which might be a bit confusing.